# Converting VTK image (.vti) data to VTK poly (.vtp) data

Tags: python, numpy, vtk

I'm trying to take some VTK image data generated from a 3-D `numpy` array and convert it into poly data so it can be read by a package that only takes .vtp as an input format. I chose to use the marching cubes algorithm to take my point/node data as input and give poly data as an output. The data is segmented into two phases (0 = black, 255 = white), so only one contour is necessary. I tried using the `vtkPolyDataReader` class to create an object for the `vtkMarchingCubes` class, then using `vtkPolyDataWriter` to take the contoured marching cubes object and save it as a VTP file:

```
import vtk
input = 'mydata.vti'

reader = vtk.vtkPolydataReader()
reader.SetFileName(input)
reader.Update()

contour = vtk.vtkMarchingCubes()
contour.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
contour.SetValue(0, 128.)
contour.Update()

writer = vtk.vtkPolyDataWriter()
writer.SetInputData(contour.GetOutput())
writer.SetFileName('mydata.vtp')
writer.Update()
writer.Write()
```

When I run the code, it takes much less time than it ought to (the input file is about 2 GB), and the VTP file the code creates is less than 1 KB. I've been banging my head against a wall over this and poring over the VTK documentation and some provided examples, but I can't figure out what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a .vtki file you need to use vtk.vtkXMLImageDataReader.  You are trying to read an image file with a vtk.vtkPolyDataReader, which is designed for reading surface meshes.

Comment: That makes sense. I changed the reader from `vtk.vtkPolyDataReader` to `vtk.vtkXMLImageDataReader()` but I'm still getting the same output issue. The VTP file is still under 1 KB. Can you tell where the problem is coming from?

Comment: can you post a sample image that you're trying to iso-surface?

Comment: Here's the original image (https://postimg.cc/PNx0s9nG) for one slice of the volume, and the Sauvola segmented version (https://postimg.cc/fJQ7jSKH) of that slice.

Comment: After experimenting with your code and image a bit, I couldn't figure out the problem.  When I print out the image from the reader, I get an image of size (1,1,1), which is clearly wrong.  Not sure what's going on.  Maybe try asking at discourse.vtk.org.